# What is the difference between .erb , .rhtml and .html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, rhtml

What is the difference between .erb, .rhtml and .html.erb?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Nothing, really. It’s just a change of philosophy between Rails 1 and Rails 2. Before Rails 2, you had file.rhtml, file.rxml and file.rjs. In Rails, that changed to file.content_type.template_engine. So with file.html.erb, the content type is html and the template engine is ERb. rxml is now xml.builder and rjs should now (mostly) be js.rjs

**In the new rails 3.0 .rhtml files will be unsupported. .html.erb is the new standard.**

Comment: Also, this new philosophy allows you to chain preprocessors. A file get preprocessed in reverse order based on extension.